# Problem with parser to my CakePHP command

Tags: cakephp

I created a command working on files in my project. It works ok, but I wanted to add a simple help with commands/subcommand description. And it is almost as I wanted it to be, but in "Usage" I have "cake" command first and I do not know how to get rid of it from there. And ideas?

[image: screen]

Comment: That is the expected, correct output, why would you want to change it?

Comment: Because my command is simple translations, without cake.

Comment: Might just be language issue, but that doesn't really make any sense to me. `cake` is the entry point for the shell application that runs your commands, hence the output is totally fine.